# Angular 4 | "Notify" component to perform an action

Tags: angular

I have a navbar component which I inject into my app using the `"< app-navbar >"` brackets, so it is loaded at all times, even when there is a route change.

I have a login system where the user gets redirected from my backend server to my frontend server together with some URL parameters. A component (`localhost:4200/auth/steam`) takes care of saving these parameters in my local storage and redirects the user to my frontend homepage (`localhost:4200/`) on success. Now that the user is logged in I want to display his username in my navbar.

The problem is that I don't have a clue on how to "notify" my navbar component to get the username from local storage so it can be displayed.

What is an elegant way of doing this?

BTW: Sorry if this question is a bit hard to understand, I just don't know how to explain it better.

BTW2: I don't think that a code example is necessary since this is rather a general question. If you need some comment below

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction read it first and then come back with a concrete issue.

Comment: can you not create an observable of local storage variable, and then subscribe to it in your navbar, as soon asa it gets the value, it will show on the UI.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I already did, but the documentation only talks about parent and child communication. My components are not related to each other

Comment: Yes, it only talks about parent-child relations despite the fact that some of the examples dont require such a relation. The service approach is the one for you

Comment: Thank you, the service example is great.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Thanks a lot again, I successfully implemented the service and it works really really great now!

Comment: Glad to hear! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say to use Observable and notify your nav bar when there is an update to your user service.

So your user service will emit a event when there is a change to the user object/variable

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private user: ReplaySubject<UserAuthorizations> = new ReplaySubject<UserAuthorizations>();
  get user() {
    return this._user.asObservable();
  }


  constructor() {
  }

  getCurrentUser(username?: string, password?: string): Observable<UserAuthorizations> {
      this.user.next('=>'+username+'-'+password);
    });
  }

}
```

Now as you are injecting/emitting the user in your service, in you nav-bar `component`, `subscribe` the user variable and it will update when ever there is a change to the user object.

```
export class myComponent {

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
     userService.user.subscribe((usr) => { 
       this.userdisplay = user.name;
     });
    }

}
```

Official angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subject and observable combination as posted by others.

Or instead of having your `<nav-bar>` component globally in app, 
you can add the `<nav-bar>` component to  individual routes.

This way the `<nav-bar>` component will be destroyed with route change and get initialized again.
On init you can get the username from local storage and set using interpolation.

Comment: The subject and observable method works great already so I will stick to my navbar being global :)

Comment: That's great. Just want to add one more point on using observable. Make sure you unsubscribe the subscription on destroy of component or it might attract memory leaks.